# Using MapBasic, is there a method to compress GeoTIFF after programatically creating the GeoTIFF?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, mapinfo, mapbasic

I need to compress the file sizes of GeoTIFFs that are created when running the MapBasic application. In a .Net application, I transform the GeoTIFF into a compressed JPG using ImageMagick; which works perfectly. However, the original GeoTIFFs are required for sharing and download. Adding to the difficulty is that the existing resolution and dimensions must be maintained. I am trying to perform the compression within MapBasic so that an additional application just to compress the GeoTIFFs will not need to be created.

Here is a sample of the current code:

```
Save Window windowId As reportPath & imgFileName & ".tif" Type "GEOTIFF" Width 7.49826 Units "in" Height 9.5816 Unites "in" Resolution 1152
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you call batch files from MapBasic?
I compress GeoTIFFs externally, using a command like the following:
gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co JPEG_QUALITY=%QUALITY% -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR -co TILED=YES
You need input & output filenames/paths after that, which I don't show here.
%QUALITY% is a variable I set up earlier, use from 75 to 100.
I'm using the gdal_translate that comes with QGIS.

Comment: yes you cann call cmd's, so it should be possible to call gdal via MapBasic